# SQL Server : unsure how to retrieve selected records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In this example, can I retrieve only rows BB, DD, and FF using T-SQL syntax and a single select statement?

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
-----------------
AA | KK | 11 | 99
BB | KK | 11 | 99   
CC | KK | 22 | 99
DD | KK | 22 | 99
EE | KK | 33 | 99
FF | KK | 33 | 99
```

Ok, so this is what I ended up with to solve my problem: SELECT distinct [C4], [C1], [C2], [C3] FROM [Table] where [C4] = 'MyValue' order by [C3] desc.

Comment: Yes, you cn do that (`select * from myTable where C1 in ('B','D','F')`), but why would you want to?

Comment: @MikeW thanks for that. To clarify, I'm creating a little messaging app that uses MSSQL as its back end. When 1 person replies to a message, it can be seen by all other subscribers to that group. Therefore (in the simplified example above) I need to retrieve only ONE reply for each previous reply (C3). So above, C1 is the serial number of the message, C2 is the text, C3 is the Index of the replies, and C4 is the conversation's ID. (Phew!) C1 is always unique, by the other three columns contain the same data for each given reply. I would like to use group by.

Comment: To clarify some more I need a select statement that only returns one of each unique entry in C3. Not Multiples

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3, C4 FROM mytable WHERE C1 IN ('BB', 'DD', 'FF')
```

If you want to unique the C3 column the query should be:

```
SELECT MAX(C1), C2, C3, C4 FROM mytable GROUP BY C2, C3, C4
```

Comment: Ok, so this is what I ended up with: SELECT distinct [C4], [C1], [C2], [C3] FROM [Table] where [C4] = 'MyValue' order by [C3] desc

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t.C1, t.C2, t.C3, t.C4 FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C3 ORDER BY C1 DESC) AS seqnum
    FROM MyTable
) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work for your particular example:

```
SELECT
  C1 = MAX(C1),
  C2,
  C3,
  C4
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  C2,
  C3,
  C4
;
```

If picking the right value from `C1` should follow a more complex logic than just getting the `MAX()` one, you'll probably need to use [@bvr's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18200496/297408) (tuning the `ORDER BY` clause properly).